# colon (:) gives load error in locale YAML file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, yaml

I have a string in `en:` locale which is

```
display_device: to play : get player
```

The colon sign is giving me error which is

> can not load translations from C:/Documents and  Settings/rajg/discoveryaws/branches/internationalization/config/locales/en.yml, expected it to return a hash, but does not

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can escape colons (and other 'important' characters) in your string if you surround it with quotes like this:

```
display_device: "to play : get player"
```